# Improve FullSimplify/ExpToTrig

Tags: simplifying-expressions

For $\frac{2 e^4}{e^8+1}$ function `ExpToTrig` returns

```
(* (2 (Cosh[4] + Sinh[4]))/(1 + Cosh[8] + Sinh[8]) *)
```

which is correct, but if I use `Simplify`/`FullSimplify`, I'll receive input value $\frac{2 e^4}{e^8+1}$ instead of obvious $\frac{1}{\cosh (4)}$ or $sech (4)$.
However, It works perfectly with $\frac{e^8+1}{2 e^4}$

```
(* Cosh[4] *)
```

Comment: The brute force workaround is `2 E^4/(E^8 + 1) // (1/# &) // FullSimplify // (1/# &)`

Comment: Your solution is good, but needs generalization, because it won't work if you add one or more terms, for example
`x + 2 E^4/(E^8 + 1) // (1/# &) // FullSimplify // (1/# &)`

Comment: Please don't add bugs tag to the question until the community/WRI has confirmed it.

Comment: OK, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
simplify[expr_] := 1/FullSimplify[1/expr]

expr1 = 2 E^4/(E^8 + 1);

expr1 // simplify

(*  Sech[4]  *)

expr2 = a + expr1;

simplify /@ expr2

(*  a + Sech[4]  *)
```